# loading certain div in the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Im triying to load a certain div in the page using ajax.load

my jquery code

```
$('nav ul li a').click( function() { 

   var pageHref=$(this).attr('href');

   $('.main_content').load(pageHref div);

return false;
});
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$('.main_content').load(pageHref + " div");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` selector is supposed to be `string`

```
$('.main_content').load(pageHref + ' div');
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax is used to load external pages within your page. If you want to load the content of a div into another on the same page then you should consider doing something like:

```
$('#id_of_destination_div').html($('#id_of_source_div').html());
```

On a side note you should try and make your questions clear as to what you are asking. This question is sort of ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.main_content').load(pageHref div);
```

Syntax here is not correct. Not sure what are you trying to do, but suppose you want to load whole `pageHref` and take a div from it which should be placed into `$(".main_content")`

In that case you should modify it like next:

```
 $('.main_content').load(pageHref + " div");
```

So, for example, pageHref equal to "www.mysite.com/page.html", than it will be equal to

```
 $('.main_content').load("www.mysite.com/page.html div");
```

(see about strings concatenation. [Here](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp) for instance)

But note that `div` specified as a selector will return **all** divs available on page, so you may find it better to use id selector:

```
 $('.main_content').load(pageHref + " #some_id");
```

in order to get only element you need.

If you want only append some content, you may do something like this:

```
$('nav ul li a').click( function() { 
   var pageHref=$(this).attr('href');
   $.get(pageHref, function(res) {$(".main_content").append(res); });
   return false;
});
```

It will load all content of pageHref  and append it to main_content

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is how it works! So  what do you want to get in result?

Comment: i want a div from another page to appear in this page's main_content, right now when i click on other page my main_content loses all its content

Comment: `Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.` - that is from [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). So, in other words it loads a page and place whole its content into `$('.main_content')`. All content that was there before will be removed. If you want to content of $('.main_content') and just need to add loaded content to the end of it, you may add another child div at the end of .main_content and use it instead. Like  $('.main_content #updatable_div').load(pageHref);

Comment: if i do ('.main_content #some_child').load(); it removes the content of the child and doesnt put anything inside

Comment: Have you checked what is returned for your request? Press f12 (you may need to install firebug for FF) and find network panel there. It will show your requests. Check what is actually returned. If you are using something like this `$('.main_content').load("www.mysite.com/page.html div");` it is possible that you have wrong selector (`div`) which returns nothing. Also, take a look at my updated answer.